# What is the purpose of CATKIN_DEPENDS?

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While looking at this `CMakeLists.txt`:

<del>https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/2eee66fd724e/tf/CMakeLists.txt</del>
https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/groovy-devel/tf/CMakeLists.txt#L25

I was wondering the exact meaning of the `CATKIN_DEPENDS` option of the `catkin_package(...)` macro was?

I would expect to see there the same packages as listed in the `find_package(...)` macro but this does not seem to be the case.

<del>b) Do we still need to copy python msg and srv manually in the install target?
Are there any other files or directories that require this special treatment?</del>

Using ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04.

Cheers, D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58498/what-is-the-purpose-of-catkin_depends?/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-19**:
For part b, you should probably make a separate question. But while you are could you explain what you mean? Are you asking if you need to manually install the .msg and .srv files? or the resulting generated code?

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-03-19**:
@William: maybe not even worth a separate question. Looking at the last 4 lines of this: https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/2eee66fd724e/tf/CMakeLists.txt I was wondering if we still need to manually copy srv and msg dirs into PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR? It was a total random discover for me...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-19**:
Looking at that issue it looks like that problem was fixed, and those last few lines are no longer needed.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-19**:
https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/10

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-03-19**:
That is how it looked to me too though I do not understand much of the code. But now I verified it and the dirs still do not get installed for my packages. How do I know if that patch was released?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-03-19**:
The reference patch to genmsg has been released long time before groovy was release. I just checked out the geometry repository, removed the manual install lines and ran "catkin_make install" and the files are getting installed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer part A of your question...

`DEPENDS` and `CATKIN_DEPENDS` are how you can tell catkin which of your package's dependencies should be passed along to packages which `find_package(...)` your package.

For example, lets say you `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` and in one of your installed headers you `#include <boost/function.hpp>`. In order for a dependent package to build and link your header they need to have Boost's include directory in the their include path and they need to link against Boost's libraries. They should get that dependency from you since you expose it in your header, i.e. they should not have to `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` just because they are building against your package, and do not otherwise use Boost.

The fact that your package depends on Boost is an implementation detail. Therefore when some `find_package(...)`'s your package they should get the dependency on Boost "for free". The way this works is that you put `DEPENDS Boost` in your `catkin_package(...)` call. Internally, catkin will `find_package(Boost)` and add `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` to `${your_pkg_LIBRARIES}` and add `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to `${your_pkg_INCLUDE_DIRS}`.

I should note that catkin will take the exact thing you give it and try to `find_package(...)` it and then try to use the `_LIBRARIES` and `_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables for that package. This assumption about `find_package(...)` layout does not always hold, as CMake does not enforce this. For example, when `find_package(...)`ing Python: `find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)` results in variables like `PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH`, and `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)` results in `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR`. Aside from case of the variable prefixes, the actual prefixes differ (`PythonLibs` -> `PYTHON`), and the suffixes are non-standard (`PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH` and `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR` vs `*_INCLUDE_DIRS`). In this case you need to pass the include dirs variable to `catkin_package(...)` explicitly using the `INCLUDE_DIRS` option and the libraries using the `LIBRARIES` option.

The `CATKIN_DEPENDS` option is exactly like that `DEPENDS` option, but you must put catkin packages only in that list. The benefit for sorting your catkin depends into a separate option is that catkin can do additional checks and warn you of potentially incorrect practices.

Finally, a simple example CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(foo)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
  system
  thread
)

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
  rosconsole
  roscpp
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
  LIBRARIES foo ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
  DEPENDS Boost
)

...
```

In this example you can see that I `find_package(Boost...)` and pass it along in the `DEPENDS` section because it generates compliant CMake variables. I `find_package(PythonLibs...)` and use it internally but do not pass it along as it is not in any of my exposed headers. I `find_package(OpenGL...)` but since it does not make compliant CMake variables I pass it along explicitly to `INCLUDE_DIRS` and `LIBRARIES`. Finally I `find_package(catkin...rosconsole roscpp)`, I use both internally, but maybe I only use rosconsole in my .c* files and therefore I do not need to pass it along, so in the `CATKIN_DEPENDS` variable I just put roscpp.

One final example, if a package uses a dependency like Boost directly they should make sure that they `find_package(...)` it explicitly and that they do not just implicitly depend on it being there from another package. An example where this occurs is that if a package `foo` exports Boost as a dependency and a package `bar` depends on `foo`, but also uses Boost internally then `bar` will compile fine without an explicit dependency on Boost. But later `foo` might decide to refactor and remove its dependency on Boost. Now `bar` will fail to compile as it does not have the implicit dependency on Boost via `foo` anymore.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 44

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-03-19**:
Great answer, thx a lot Will.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-19**:
This seems to be a common misunderstanding surrounding catkin and chaining dependencies. I might post it in the wiki, or rework it as a tutorial.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-26**:
This is very helpful. However, regarding your example,`why INCLUDE_DIRS` does not have `${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}`, `CATKIN_DEPENDS` does not have rosconsole? And why `DEPENDS` does not have `OpenGL` or `PythonLibs`?

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2016-08-09**:
Thank you so much for the in depth explanation! Just one quick question, the example assumes OpenGl is used in header files, right?

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2017-01-16**:
It definitely should be in the [CMakeLists wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt). This answer is a wiki itself. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2019-01-10**:
I'm still not convinced. You do `find_package` for `Boost` because your header refer to it. But the library `foo` will have a `target_link_library` for `Boost` later on, otherwise it would not compile. There should be no need to do the same for a package which links against `foo`.

**Comment by [mcamurri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38531/mcamurri/) on 2019-01-10**:
Or are you just saying that `CATKIN_DEPENDS` and `DEPENDS` should contain the only libraries which appear in headers which are not included and compiled inside the package itself (e.g. a header only library)? Would I need to specify any dependency if there are no libraries declared?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2019-03-08**:
If I have a Python-only package without generated messages, should I add something to CATKIN_DEPENDS? I know practically that I can leave it empty, but the question is if it is correct also "theoretically". Also, do Python-only packages only need `<exec_depend>` tags in package.xml? Overall, I'm missing some good documentation for Python-only packages on the Wiki. E.g. [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy) the wiki suggests to add `<build_depend>python-numpy`, but is it really needed?

**Comment by [AlecPath](https://answers.ros.org/users/60654/alecpath/) on 2021-02-15**:
@mcamurri I have the same question as you. It seems like if library `X` of project `foo` has a public dependency on library `external_sys_library` then it shouldn't be necessary to list `external_sys_library` in the `DEPENDS` section.